# Wix: Populate repeater with external API call

Tags: content-management-system, velo

I'm referring to the following video [How to Create A Web App With External API Access using Wix Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIbB5qVQp9Y) & wanted to know how I would populate a repeater rather than populating a paragraph tag as shown in the youtube video mentioned above.

Basically here is the pseudocode of what I would like to achieve:

```
If search box is equal to null or empty
    Display all crypto currencie(s)
else
    Display single crypto currency
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want to accomplish. I think you want to display a repeater item for each currency when the search box is empty. Each repeater item will have its info displayed in a text element as in the video. And when there is a search term, only one repeater item will display with the info in a text element as well. Is that correct?

Comment: @Sam apologies if I was not very clear, however your observation to my problem above is 100% correct.
Unfortunately I've tried a couple of scenarios to achieve this to no avail :-(!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the info in a repeater isn't too different than what the example already shows. Actually, when the search box is empty, the API returns an array that just needs a little playing with to get it to work with a repeater.

So, assuming you added a repeater with the ID `repeater1` that contains a text element with the id `result`, you can make the following minor changes to the page code. You don't need to touch the backend code at all.

First, in the `button1_click` event handler we'll remove the code that populates the text element with the data returned from the API. Instead, we'll add an `_id` property to each currency object (required for the repeater) and then feed that data to the repeater.

```
export function button1_click(event) {
  getCryptoCurrencyInfo($w("#currencyInput").value)
    .then(currencyInfo => {
      // add an _id property to each currency object
      currencyInfo.forEach(item => item._id = item.id);
      // feed the data to the repeater
      $w('#repeater1').data = currencyInfo;
    } );
}
```

Then, we can take the code for populating the text element and stick it in the `repeater1_itemReady` event handler. This function will run once for each currency item in the array fed to the repeater's `data` property. Make sure you use the properties panel to wire the function to the matching repeater event.

```
export function repeater1_itemReady($item, itemData, index) {
  $item("#result").text = "Name: " + itemData.name + "\n"
    + "Symbol: " + itemData.symbol + "\n"
    + "Rank: " + itemData.rank + "\n"
    + "Price (USD): " + itemData.price_usd + "\n"
    + "Market Capitalization (USD): " + itemData.market_cap_usd + "\n"
    + "Percent Change 1h: " + itemData.percent_change_1h + "\n"
    + "Percent Change 24h: " + itemData.percent_change_24h + "\n"
    + "Percent Change 7d: " + itemData.percent_change_7d;
}
```

Notice two subtle changes to the code. First, we use `$item` instead of `$w` to select the text element. This selects the specific instance of the text element in the current repeater element. Second, we use `itemData` instead of `currencyInfo[0]`. This gives us the specific data that is associated with the current repeater element.

Comment: Thanks very much Sam I'm going to give it a go right now.
I'll accept your answer as soon as I've got it working from my end ;-).