# WIX API fetch to repeater

Tags: api, repeater, velo

I am experiencing issues populating wix API fetched data to a repeater, though i did follow some example here i get an error, not sure why...

Link to a example: [Wix: Populate repeater with external API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56821349/wix-populate-repeater-with-external-api-call/59011583#59011583)

**here is the error:**

```
Wix code SDK error: Each item in the items array must have a member named `_id` which contains a unique value identifying the item.
Wix code SDK Warning: The data that was passed to data contained at least two items with the same ID: . Only the first item was accepted.
```

my current code

```
import {getCurrentTemp} from 'backend/serviceModule';

//...

    export function buttonFetch_click(event, $w) {
      getCurrentTemp($w("#emailInput").value)
        .then(CurrentTemp => {
          // add an _id property to each  object
          CurrentTemp.forEach(item => item._id = item.id)
          // feed the data to the repeater
          $w('#repeater1').data = CurrentTemp;
        } );
    }

    export function repeater1_itemReady($item, itemData, index) {
      $item("#textResults").text = "Name: " + itemData.Title + "\n"
        + "Symbol: " + itemData.BreachDate + "\n"
        + "Rank: " + itemData.Description + "\n"
        + "Price (USD): " + itemData.DataClasses;
    }
```

Comment: Please help on this plz...posted a day ago..no help yet!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each item must have unique id.

Install `uuid` here https://support.wix.com/en/article/corvid-managing-external-code-libraries-with-the-package-manager

and setup id for each item

```
import uuid from 'uuid';

// .....

$w('#repeater1').data = CurrentTemp.map((item) => {
  item._id = uuid();
  return item;
});

// .....
```

Comment: Thanks I solved this anyway...different method... Thanks though